# How to force only two state (expanded and collapsed) of CollapsingToolbarLayour?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to have the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (inside the `AppBarLayout`) which  **expands/collapses when user get up finger**. When user hold and move the finger on screen the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` should simultaneously change size (the standard behavior).

My problem is part: "**`CollapsingToolbarLayout` expands/collapses when user get up finger**
I have standard solution from material support library (**inside a fragment**):

(I remove not important attributes):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I try to handle onTouch event like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.app_bar).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                counter++;
                Log.d("tag toolbar_layout", "=== ACTION_DOWN "+ counter);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                counter--;
                Log.d("tag toolbar_layout", " == ACTION_UP " +counter);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                counter--;
                Log.d("tag toolbar_layout", " == ACTION_CANCEL "+ counter);

            break;
        default:
            Log.d("tag toolbar_layout", "onTouch "+ event.getAction());
        }

        return true;
    }
```

but I almost receive `ACTION_CANCEL` and very rare `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` is too early I still hold finger on screen when the app receive that event. And after `ACTION_CANCEL` the app doesn't receive any even no longer so. I cannot call `setExpanded(true, true)` on appbar.

So question is: there is another way to get info that user get up finger form `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you are trying to completely expand/collapse the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` after the user stops scrolling (The users has lifted his finger from the screen)? The `AppBarLayout` provides a scroll-flag to snap the content [1] to provide this effect:

> public static final int SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP
>
> Upon a scroll ending, if the view is only partially visible then it
>   will be snapped and scrolled to it's closest edge. For example, if the
>   view only has it's bottom 25% displayed, it will be scrolled off
>   screen completely. Conversely, if it's bottom 75% is visible then it
>   will be scrolled fully into view.

[1]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP